# Differential Backup problems on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

I have a maintenance plan that takes full backups on wed and sunday at 12am and a differential backups on Mon. Tues, Thur , Fri and Sat'day. The Problem i came across was when ever a full backup happens on wed and sun the differential backup plan fails specifically for 2 databases 'abc1' and 'abc2' with an error

> Executing the query "BACKUP DATABASE XXX TO  DISK =  failed with the following error:
>   Cannot perform a differential backup for database "abc1", because a current database backup does not exist. Perform a full database backup by reissuing BACKUP DATABASE, omitting the WITH DIFFERENTIAL option. BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>
> Possible failure reasons:
>   Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established...  The package execution fa...  The step failed."

I had to perform a manual full backup for these two databases and had to run the differential backup job manually.

Example : When a full backup job runs on sunday at 12am, the differential fails for the two databases with the above error on monday 12am and i had to manually take full backup on monday for the 2 databases and run the differential job and it run fine on tuesday at 12am and on wed'day when the full backup job runs again, the differential fails again for 2 databases on thur 12am with the same error and i had to do the manual process again.

Comment: do you have any processes that change your recovery model for those two databases, between backups?

Comment: no , this db's are in production , no changes would be made to the recovery model @DimUser

Comment: you will need to run backup differential as next setp  on success of full backup job in same job

Comment: @TheGameiswar what would be the point in that?

Comment: I suspect ,user is running both jobs in parallel or separate jobs,full backup when it starts ,it clears differential bits,so I suppose this may be the cause

Comment: @Nani what account is the diff backup job running under? does it have the appropriate permissions? Presumably it's working for you as you are "sys admin"?

Comment: @TheGameiswar unless I have misread, hasn't the backup schedule been supplied? I read that as two separate jobs on separate days?

Comment: I missed the separate days part,as long as there is a full backup (doesn't matter how old) diff backup should work..May be full backup failed

Comment: no the full backups happen as per schedule @TheGameiswar

Comment: @DimUser it just for the 2 databases the job fails , the maintenance plan takes diff backup for all databases.

Answer (score 1):

Try stopping the "SQL Server VSS Writer" service and change the start up mode to **manual**.
You might want to restart your computer.